# How to prevent automatic slideup in css menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to prevent automatic slide up on my css menu when I click the list item.I herewith attached my java script and I also want to highlighted(colored) the selected list item on the css menu.I already used stop().slideup() function,but still it's not work for me.

```js
( function( $ ) {
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function() {
  $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).closest('li').addClass('active'); 
  var checkElement = $(this).next();
  if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
    $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
    checkElement.slideUp('normal');
  }
  if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
    $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
    checkElement.slideDown('normal');
  }
  if($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false; 
  }  
});
});
} )( jQuery );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery slideUp on click, stopped on hover reset on mouseleave](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20458207/jquery-slideup-on-click-stopped-on-hover-reset-on-mouseleave)

Answer (score 0):

Put slideup as none like slideup('none');